# Minecraft launcher freezes after downloading an update

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, minecraft-launcher

I downloaded the newest version of the Minecraft launcher at minecraft.net/download but for some reason when I enter the launcher and press the play button it would just load the green bar above it and which I know full well that its downloading the update or some version. But after its finished loading it just freeze and stops working. If anyone has an advice, it would be incredibly helpful. I've also deleted and re-downloaded it.

Comment: Same problem...

Comment: Where exactly does it freeze? Does it get to the white Mojang screen? Or does it freeze on the launcher screen? How long have you waited after download before calling it frozen? I had a similar problem, so hopefully I can help you resolve the issue.

Answer (score -1):

After it freezes you could just leave it open for a few hours or something and don't do anything to it. Sometimes it just takes time to fix.